# Celery sees my task but does not execute it

Tags: python, redis, celery

I'm trying to run a celery chain in local, with a Redis broker.

**The problem:** As you can see below the worker command, tasks are not ran. Nothing happens.

Find below all the informations needed.

**The redis-server is running**

```
redis-server
[15048] 05 Feb 11:36:30 * Server started, Redis version 2.4.5
[15048] 05 Feb 11:36:30 * DB loaded from disk: 0 seconds
[15048] 05 Feb 11:36:30 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
...
```

**The celery beat is also running**

```
celery beat -b redis://localhost:6379/0
celery beat v4.2.1 (windowlicker) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2020-02-05 11:37:30
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379/0
    . loader -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%WARNING
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
```

But when I run the worker, it can see the tasks, but does not execute them:

```
celery -A module.tasks worker --loglevel=info -Q training_queue -P eventlet

[tasks]
  . module.tasks.generate_the_chain
  . module.tasks.post_pipeline_message
  . module.tasks.train_by_site_post

[2020-02-05 11:39:14,700: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2020-02-05 11:39:16,746: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-02-05 11:39:20,804: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2020-02-05 11:39:21,836: INFO/MainProcess] pidbox: Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0.
[2020-02-05 11:39:22,850: INFO/MainProcess] celery@HOST ready.
```

Nothing happens after this line.

BELOW is the code:

**init**.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery 

CELERY_APP_NAME = 'app_name'
CELERY_BROKER = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_BACKEND = CELERY_BROKER


CELERY = Celery(CELERY_APP_NAME, 
                backend=CELERY_BACKEND,
                broker=CELERY_BROKER,
                include=['module.tasks']
                )
```

And tasks.py

```
import os
import logging
import time
from celery import Celery, chain, signature
from celery.schedules import crontab
from module import CELERY


@CELERY.on_after_finalize.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    site_id = "f1ae"

    sign = signature(
        'module.tasks.generate_the_chain',
        args=(site_id),
        queue='training_queue'
    )
    sender.add_periodic_task(5.0, sign, name='training')


@CELERY.task
def generate_the_chain(site_id):
    print("Hello World")
    """
    This function run the chain of functions and is then
    scheduled with Celery beat
    """

    chain = signature(
        'module.tasks.site_post',
        args=(site_id),
        queue='training_queue'
    )

    chain |= signature(
        'module.tasks.post_pipeline_message',
        args=(),
        queue='training_queue'
    )

    chain.apply_async()


@CELERY.task
def site_post(site_id):

    print(f"Hello {site_id}")

    return True

@CELERY.task
def post_pipeline_message(success):
    if success is True:
        LOGGER.info("Pipeline build with success")
```

Comment: Did you try to run the task manually?

Comment: If I run generate_the_chain(), the function starts but then I have this error:
TypeError: site_post() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given.

If I run setup_period_task(CELERY), it just run the function and nothing more

Comment: Result of the previous signature is passed as argument to the next one. Maybe that is why you see the error... I assume the code you executed is not the same code you wrote above, right?

Comment: Yeah it takes the result of the previous, but I don't see why it's an issue? 

The first signature returns a True, and the second one expects it.